# Generating Functional for Complex Scalar Theory

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, path-integral, propagator, klein-gordon-equation

The generating functional for a free complex scalar field theory is given by:

$$W[J,J^*]=\int D\phi D\phi^* \exp (i  \int_{}^{} d⁴ x [(\partial_{\mu}\phi)^*(\partial^{\mu}\phi) -m^2\phi^*\phi + J^*\phi + J\phi^*] ).$$

In order to compute it one has to make the following change of variables:

$$\phi ^{'}(x)= \phi(x) + \int\Delta (x-z)J(z). $$

Why isn't it $\phi ^{'}(x)= \phi(x) + \int\Delta (x-z)J^*(z)$ instead given that in the generating functional one has $J^*\phi$?

Answer (score 1):

**Disclamer**: I think you have a error sign in the change of variables. But the concept remains the same.

The change of variables is done to get in the end a gaussian integral in the fields that you can compute. To do so you first have to complete the square in the exponential. If we call $$D = (\partial_\mu\partial^\mu+m^2)$$ the you see that, integrating by parts $$(\partial_\mu\phi^*)(\partial^\mu\phi)-m^2\phi^*\phi \to -\phi^*(\partial_\mu\partial^\mu+m^2)\phi = -\phi^*D\phi$$ With this we can easily complete the square using

$$-(\phi^*-D^{-1}J^*)D(\phi-D^{-1}J)+D^{-1}J^*J = -\phi^*D\phi+D^{-1}J^*D\phi+\phi^*DD^{-1}J+D^{-1}J^*J\\=-\phi^*D\phi+J^*\phi+\phi^*J$$

Which is exactly what you have in your exponential. Now we can write the integral kernel of $D^{-1}$ so that $$\phi^*-D^{-1}J^* \to \phi^*(x)-\int\Delta_F(x-y)J^*(y)dy$$

You can easily see that if you complete the square in the way you said, e.g. mixing $\phi$ with $J^*$ and viceversa, you won't get the initial lagrangian since the current interaction terms would be $$J\phi+J^*\phi^*$$ which is not what you want.